# iPhone Update Queueing

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I've got a plan to release several updates over the next year for an app depending on season, events, etc. I know that you can release an update with an availability date, however what I haven't being able to find is if you can queue up several updates with individual release dates throughout the year.

Each of course with the functionality of the last.

Cheers

Comment: you downloaded this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is NO.

Reason is that you cannot add new version to your app, until your application status is "Ready For Sale".

Hope this info helps you..